# The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.Helpers.Chart'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am getting error :  The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.Helpers.Chart'

Please help me in resolving this. Here is the code developed with mvc and razor syntax:

Model

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;

  namespace Chart.Models
  {
            public class FooBarModel
            {
                public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Locations { get; set; }
            }
  }
```

Controller:

```
        using Chart.Models;
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.Mvc;

        namespace Chart.Controllers
        {
            public class FooController : Controller
            {
                //
                // GET: /Foo/

                public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    var locations = new[]
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "US", Text = "United States" },
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "CA", Text = "Canada" },
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "MX", Text = "Mexico" },
                    };

                    var model = new FooBarModel
                    {
                        Locations = locations,
                    };

                    return View(model);
                }       
            }
        }
```

[image]

View Code:

```
        @model Chart.Models.FooBarModel             // intellisense shows error on this line as well

        @{
            Layout = null;
        }

        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            <title>Index</title>
            <script>
                var locations = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Locations));
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>        
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: What happens if you build your project?

Comment: "Build succeded" is the message shown and it runs but the webpage shows the error.

Comment: this sounds like it can't find it.  If you just put FooBarModel and type ctrl . it should bring in the full path to that model for you

Comment: where should i type this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could fully qualify the namespace to avoid the collision with the `System.Web.Helpers.Chart` class which is in scope in the view:

```
@model global::Chart.Models.FooBarModel
```

Basically it's a bad idea to use class names in your namespaces. For example `Chart` is a class defined in the `System.Web.Helpers` namespace.

For example:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyApplication.Models
```