# Why am I getting CS0426 error when I give project name 'MvcApplication' using ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, visual-studio-2015, namespaces

This is really weird. As it sounds, I have tried to create a project/solution named **MvcApplication** using `Visual Studio 2015` `(Enterprise)`.  I choose `MVC` template and leave all default as it is.

It created successfully. I build solution without any errors or warnings. When I run the project (start debugging) it loads ASP.NET MVC home page, which is fine. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jj29.png)

When I click Register immediately throws an error CS0426: The type name `Models` does not exist in the type `MvcApplication`.

in source file some where in temp folder. (Screenshot attached). 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRs6i.png)

So far I tried to solve this problem using following 
1. Close solution and restart machine. (did not work)
2. Delete all temporary file (did not work)
3. Create other application with different name (worked)
4. Add new project in above solution with same name 'MvcApplication' (same issue - did not work, but it proves that there is an issue with name MvcApplication.)
5. Google it (Not much help regarding CS0426 error) - It does not make any sense. (Why?)
6. MSDN, StackOverflow, other blogging reported error but not cause or solution? still puzzled why?

I wish I could be help but I need to confirm that you can not name your project 'MvcApplication' in your solution and expect to work. I could be wrong. But I need more proof in this case.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `Register` view has this model binding:

```
@* Register view *@
@model MvcApplication.Models.RegisterViewModel
```

Since you have `MvcApplication` as project/solution name (including project namespace), it is possible to have naming conflict with `MvcApplication` class that already provided in `Global.asax` when defining view model:

```
// Global.asax
namespace MvcApplication
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        // other stuffs here
    }
}

// Model class
namespace MvcApplication.Models // ==> potential naming collision when being used in view
{
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
       // some properties here
    }
}
```

To avoid collision with `MvcApplication` class shown like above, you can use `global` with fully qualified name like this one in view page:

```
@model global::MvcApplication.Models.RegisterViewModel
```

or simply **changing project namespace** into different name.

Similar issue:

[The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.Helpers.Chart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590821/the-type-name-models-does-not-exist-in-the-type-system-web-helpers-chart)

Comment: Thanks for valuable inputs.

Comment: Instead of just saying thanks, take a little time reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to find out what you should do when someone provides help/explanation.

Comment: I am sorry I can not vote for following reason. 
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.